# Question about if statement in function in javascript - how if the if statement return true but the function return false

Tags: javascript, function

can i ask you guys a question?
Below is my code:

```
var num = 1;
var isNumberEqualOne = function(){
    if(num == 1){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}();
alert(isNumberEqualOne);
```

In this code, the statement in the function return true, after return true, the code in the function is still executing right? So at the end, the code meet return false, so why the function still return true.Sorry for my bad english.Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`return` will halt the function and return immediately. The remaining body of code in the function will *not* be executed.

In your example, `num` is assigned `1`, so the condition inside your function is `true`. This means that your function will return there and then with `true`.

You could also rewrite that function so its body is `return (num == 1)`.

Answer (score 6):

As [alex said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183668/question-about-if-statement-in-function-in-javascript-how-if-the-if-statement-r/6183685#6183685), the `return` function transfers control out of the function call immediately; no other statements in the function (other than `finally` blocks) are executed.

So:

```
function foo(a) {
    if (a == 1) {
        alert("a is 1");
        return;
        alert("This never happens, it's 'dead code'");
    }
    alert("a is not 1");
}
foo(1); // alerts "a is 1" and nothing else
foo(2); // alerts "a is not 1"
```

Regarding what I said above that *"no other statements in the function **(other than `finally` blocks)** are executed"*, more about `finally` blocks:

```
function foo(a) {
    try {
        if (a == 3) {
            throw "a is e";
        }
        if (a == 1) {
            alert("a is 1");
            return;
            alert("This never happens, it's 'dead code'");
        }
        alert("a is not 1");
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert("exception: " + e);
    }
    finally {
        alert("finally!");
    }
}
foo(1); // alerts "a is 1", then "finally!"
foo(2); // alerts "a is not 1", then "finally!"
foo(3); // alerts "exception: a is 3", then "finally!"
```

Note that no matter how the execution leaves the `try/catch` block, either naturally by falling out the bottom, or early because of `return`, or early because of an exception, the code in the `finally` block *always* runs.

---

**Off-topic**: Separately, note that you need parentheses around that function expression if you're going to call it immediately like that:

```
    var isNumberEqualOne = (function(){
//                         ^--- here
        if(num == 1){
           return true;
        }
        return false;
    })();
//   ^--- and here
```

or you can put the `()` that call it within the parens like this:

```
    var isNumberEqualOne = (function(){
//                         ^--- here
        if(num == 1){
           return true;
        }
        return false;
    }());
//     ^--- and here
```

Either works.

Comment: BTW, I was reading a JavaScript blog post yesterday titled *Closures are not complicated*. Imagine my surprise when I realised you were the author :P

Answer (score 0):

When a function executes a return statement, it will not continue executing statements that appear after it.  So if `num == 1` evaluates to `true`, then the function will return `true`.

Note also that your alert statement is not calling the `isNumberEqualOne` function.  You should do `alert(isNumberEqualOne())` if you want the function to be called.

Comment: *"Note also that your alert statement is not calling the isNumberEqualOne function."* There *is* no `isNumberEqualOne` function. It's a boolean. He calls the anonymous function immediately upon defining it and stores the *result* of it in `isNumberEqualOne`.